# What is this mistake "Illegal string offset 'id'"?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the value of json for example

```
function notification(Request $request){
    $registers =$request->get('json');
    return $registers[0]["id"];
}
```

But I get this error:""Illegal string offset 'id'"

This method is called for post:

```
<input type="hidden" name="json[]" value="{{json_encode($item,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)}}">
```

and the route is:

```
$app->post('notification','AtlanticControllerChangePrice@notification');
```

and a item have:

```
> {"id":"30264379-6648-f55e-6a67-588a440d7329","name":"Cambio
> Precio","lista":"OVG","oficina_ventas":"1100","lista_precios":"17","tipo_precio":"LISTA","nit":"32466669","producto":"304","material":"CHUCK
> FLAT - CERTIFIED ANGUS
> BEFF","unidad_medida":"KG","precio_actual":"46000","nuevo_precio":"49800","fecha_inicio":"2017-01-16","cod":"1000473","cliente":"","procesado":"0","idClient":"b6d23a02-ac53-c327-83e6-587e1177a94d","name_client":"POSADA
> DE POSADA INES LUCIA PATRICI"}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($registers)` to see what's contained within?

Comment: is `$registers[0]` the item which is shown in your json-Dump? I would guess, that your trying to access an item which is not there. 

What happens if you're using `$registers["id"]` instead?

Comment: @Juned 

array(48) { [0]=> string(473) "{"id":"30264379-6648-f55e-6a67-588a440d7329","name":"Cambio Precio","lista":"OVG","oficina_ventas":"1100","lista_precios":"17","tipo_precio":"LISTA","nit":"32466669","producto":"304","material":"CHUCK FLAT - CERTIFIED ANGUS BEFF","unidad_medida":"KG","precio_actual":"46000","nuevo_precio":"49800","fecha_inicio":"2017-01-16","cod":"1000473","cliente":"","procesado":"0","idClient":"b6d23a02-ac53-c327-83e6-587e1177a94d","name_client":"POSADA DE POSADA INES LUCIA PATRICI"}

Comment: @takethefake return this error :Undefined index: id

Comment: You need to use the json_decode function to parse the string first.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing json_decode and also removed name="json[]" to name="json" and it worked,thanks!!! @Juned